# is it possible to use OpenGL lighting without declaring surface normals?

Tags: opengl, glut, opengl-es-lighting

is it possible to declare lighting on objects without declaring surfaces normals?

steps i'm willing to do are:

```
1. enable lighting
2. define surface material 
3. define lighting position
4. define lighting parms : ambient....
```

is it enough or do i have to put somewhere there also glNormal ?

Answer (score 6):

You can't compute lighting without knowing what direction the surface is facing. That direction is called the *surface normal*. So either you're going to have to provide one, or you're going to have to compute one in a shader. And the latter is somewhat unlikely in the general case.

So yes, you need to provide vertex normals to do lighting.